# Bitlocker encryption disables Android phone memory card

Tags: windows-7, windows, bitlocker

I used Bitlocker to lock the memory card of my Android phone. Now i can't even access it anymore, even the dialog box that prompts for password doesn't display at all. When i plug my phone into my laptop i don't see my memory card under "devices with removable storage". Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your phone can't understand the card anymore. You'll have to format the card, removing Bitlocker, for the phone to be able to access it. Ideally you would use the phone to reformat it.